# Clarification on pointer to member of base

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, c++20

Experimenting with member pointers, I came a across some unexpected behavior. I need to ask whether this behavior is a UB or undocumented behavior or just a compiler bug. The test was run on **Visual Studio 2022** with **msvc** toolchain as well as **llvm**. I asking for pointers to reputable references on standard or platform-specific behavior. And I'm afraid I can not accept a mere **don't** as an answer. The problem in question is the result of an oversimplification of some library features.

consider simple metadate listing below:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_foo = requires{ {&T::foo}; };

template<typename U>
requires has_foo<U>
constexpr static auto foo_address = &U::foo;

template<typename U>
requires has_foo<U>
using foo_type = std::remove_const_t<decltype(foo_address<U>)>;
```

Constraining the templates does not change the results - but it is there for furthur expressiveness. We are going to test the following `baz` classes:

```
struct bar {
    int foo(){};
};

struct baz1: bar {
};

struct baz2: bar {
    using bar::foo;
};

struct baz3: private bar {
    using bar::foo;
};
```

the test function to be used is:

```
template <typename t>
void foo_test() {
    endl(std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<decltype(&t::foo), foo_type<t>>);
    endl(std::cout << typeid(&t::foo).name());
    endl(std::cout << typeid(decltype(&t::foo)).name());
    endl(std::cout << typeid(foo_type<t>).name());
};
```

**msvc** fails to compile for `baz3` with hard error on `foo_address` and `foo_type`, while **clang** accepts it.
I need to learn the stance of standards against such behavior.

Thank you all,
FM.

Comment: @user17732522 the pointer-to-member type is a `constexpr` type. It can even be used as none-type template parameters. So No, that is not the issue.

Comment: "the pointer-to-member type is a constexpr type" This phrase doesn't make much sense to me. `int` constants can be used as non-type template parameters, but `int` is not the same as `const int`. Why do you expect something different from pointer-to-member types?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I don't expect any difference. What is known at compile-time is `costexpr`. And any type with some values detectable at compile-time is a `constexpr` type. Note the difference from `const`. The later is just a promise to not modify an object in the declaration context, while the former means compile-time constant with no runtime side-effects. That actually applies to variables. With functions its more like a hint.

Comment: @Red.Wave They are descripting why the first line is `false`.  `decltype(&t::foo)` is not (top level) `const`, `foo_address<U>` is (top level) `const`.  The types are not identical, so `is_same_v` returns ... `false`.  This is a quirk of the language.  I am not sure what you are arguing against here.  The MSVC "access through private" is a different issue, unaddressed by any of these comments; that happens when you raise two actually different issues often.  :)

Comment: @user17732522 look at the output. The typestrings are identical. I know what I am discussing. You may need to focus more. Search keywords: `constexpr`, **pointer to member**.

Comment: So I need to try some `std::remove_const` sort of thing. The other problem is still asking for an answer

Comment: @user17732522 good point. I need to edit the question

Comment: OK guys. constness problem solved. Let's dig the compilation issue. @Yakk-AdamNevraumont

Comment: I have no idea what a constexpr type is. There is no such beast in the C++ standard. `constexpr` is a *decl-specifier*. `const` is a *cv-qualifier*. The former apply to declarations while the latter apply to types.

Comment: Next, it would be useful to post the actual errors.  In full (including any errors), in a quoted-code block (`>` followed by 5+ spaces makes quoted-code).  Often those errors are useful.

Comment: From [the error message](https://godbolt.org/z/qYn4dxPhG) it looks like nonsense on the part of MSVC; it thinks `foo` is a private member in the context of `baz3`.  It even allows `&baz3::foo`, just not in that template context.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont that's my guess too. But only if there is a documet on it. That is the soul of my question.

Comment: Looks like an msvc bug to me. If you replace `foo` with a data member, it compiles, but if you make it a static member function instead, it still fails. Doesn't make any sense to me.